# How can I add custom fonts on Maven for Jasper Reports

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports, tomcat6

I been trying to follow the example on this page:
http://grysz.com/2010/06/01/use-custom-fonts-in-jasperreports-pdf-exporter/ 
Still, when I ran the reports on maven, I get that my font is not available to the JVM at run-time as an error from tomcat.
Anyone has had experience adding fonts to Maven for a jasper report and can give me a little better instructions to accomplish this? I been trying this already for too long and it does not seem to work correctly.
Thanks,

Patrick

Comment: Is your application a maven-based?

Comment: Did you build jar with fonts and deployed it to the maven repository?

Comment: Yes sir. :). Maven compile is not complaining. However when Jasper is meant to access the fonts, it just doesn't

Comment: Hmmm. Did you try to run a standalone java application (not maven) with fonts in classpath (guarantee)?

Comment: I actually did. I thought it had to do something with dependencies, but as a stand alone app, it works just fine. I am just stuck on this. BTW don't want you to worry much right now on this, go enjoy thanksgiving!

Comment: I'm not clear on the exact meaning of "when I ran the reports on maven". Maven builds... but it doesn't really run reports, does it?

Comment: mdahl. You are correct, it should simply run like a compiled application and drop back the report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using iReport you can export fonts as an extension. 
Then you

1. can place your font.jar in your application and create an system-scope-dependency,
2. or you can maven install your font into your repository.

---

By the way:

You can skip those error-messages using the jasperreports.properties.

```
# ignore missing fonts in reports
net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font=true
```

Comment: Hey Peter. I have tried both. I really don't want to do the missing font. I actually need that font working, so I need to know if it fails (in other words I left that on, on purpose. Still I still get JVM dependency failure

Comment: Ok, let me see... do u get the same dependency failure?

Comment: Hey Peter. I am giving you the point. I went back, and re installed the font without any dashes, asterisks, etc, and it worked in maven this time. I don't know if that is a recurrent issue, but that fixed the problem.

Comment: @Truesky what do you mean by "re installed the font without any dashes, asterisks, etc"?

Comment: Wow, Sorry Christian, I did miss your comment. The font name had dashes in it, and at the time I was using it I simply removed the dash names from the font name and placed again in the fonts folder. That did the trick and I was able to reference the fonts. I am sure by now there is a better way to do this, but I moved away from jasper for at least 4 years now.